# IIS Hosted WCF Service won't accept https endpoint, receive 404 resource error

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis, ssl, wshttpbinding

Despite all of my efforts, I have not been able to get my simple WCF service hosted on IIS with SSL.

We are using windows server 2k3 with IIS 6.0 and we have up to .NET 4.0 installed on the server (web site is configured for 4.0)

If i go to http//.../rptService.svc url, I get the .svc page with the code blocks and ?wsdl url

on the other hand, if i go to https//.../rptService.svc I get a "Resource not found" 404 error. (colons on urls are removed b/c of spam prevention)

The web site has a working SSL certificate enabled for it.

My relevant web.config file is as follows:

```
    <system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding name="rptBinding">
        <security mode="Transport">
          <transport clientCredentialType="None"/>
        </security>
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="wcfApp.rptServiceBehavior">
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="false" httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceTimeouts/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="wcfApp.rptServiceBehavior"
            name="wcfApp.rptService">
          <endpoint binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="rptBinding"  contract="wcfApp.rptService" 
                    address="">
          </endpoint>
            <endpoint name="MetadataBinding" address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
        </service>
    </services>
```

I have tried just about 100 different ways to write the web.config file from 150 different blog/web posts with similar situations, and have not gotten anything to work thus far.

My end goal is to get this wcf service hosted accepting a username/password token with a custom user name validator, but right now I can't even get it working with SSL!

Application is being built in VS 2010.

Please let me know if there is any more information that I can provide.

Any help is appreciated!